# Scheduled Reminders: From Email Address

Tags: scheduled-reminders

Quick question: where does the Scheduled Reminders job get its "from" email address from? Ours is sending the upcoming activity reminders using an old domain and I can't figure out where I can change that. I've changed all the main emails of things I know (the from email addresses list, the main org contact email, the admin/org contact page, etc).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's on each of the individual scheduled reminders. Admin - communications - scheduled reminders.